# Смещение счетчика при удалении блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код, который динамически формирует поля формы и поле `<select>` для выбора вопроса связки. Но если я удаляю поле из середины списка, допустим поля **1-2-3** и удаляю **2**, то остаются поля **1-3**, проблема в том, что мне необходимо сместить все поля которые находятся ниже, чтобы стало **1-2** после удаления и сместить нумерацию полей `select` тоже(это к тому, что просто сменить цифры в нельзя, тогда в `select` будет отображаться лишний вопрос). Удалить просто **3** вместо **2** я не могу, если в **3** блоке будет какая-то информация, а удалят **2** блок, то информация из **3** исчезнет.

```js
function addField() {
  var text = "";
  var telnum = parseInt($('#add_field_area').find('div.add:last').attr('id').slice(3)) + 1;

  for (i = 1; i < telnum; i++) {
    text += '<option>Вопрос ' + i + '</option>';
  }

  $('div#add_field_area').append('<div id="add' + telnum + '" class="add"><label> Поле №' + telnum + ' </label><textarea name="val[]"></textarea><select class="chzn-select' + telnum + '" name="require[]">' + text + '</select><span class="deletebutton" onclick="deleteField(' + telnum + ');"> удалить</span></div>');


}

function deleteField(id) {

  $("div#add" + id).remove();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add_field_area">
  <div id="add1" class="add">
    <label> Поле №1</label>
    <textarea name="val[]"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Добавить поле" onClick="addField();">
```

UPD. Код со вложенными блоками:

```html
<div id="add_field_area">    
    <div id="block1" class="block">
        <div class="number">1.</div>    
        <div class="wrapAreas">
            <div class="wrapTextarea">
                <textarea></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapSelect">
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотри, убрал функцию delete, добавил функцию rePain которая будет перерисовывать форму.
Плюсы:

1. Не нужно заморачиваться с цифрами
2. При изменении функции addField, все изменения коснуться и rePain

```js
//Добавляем поле
function addField(count, textTextarea) {
 var text = "";
 var countInput = (count > 0 ? count : ($(".add").length + 1));
 var textTextarea = (textTextarea != undefined ? textTextarea : '')
 
 for (i = 1; i < countInput; i++) {
  text += '<option>Вопрос ' + i + '</option>';
 }

 $('div#add_field_area').append('<div id="add' + countInput + '" class="add"><label> Поле №' + countInput + ' </label><textarea data-id="'+countInput+'" name="val[]">'+textTextarea+'</textarea><select class="chzn-select' + countInput + '" name="require[]">' + text + '</select><span class="deletebutton" onclick="rePain(' + countInput + ');"> удалить</span></div>');
}

//Рисуем форму заново
function rePain(id){
 objText = {};
 
 a = 2;
 $("div#add_field_area .add").each(function(i, obj){
  if(i != 0){
   if((i + 1) != id){
    objText[a] = {text:$(obj).find('textarea').val()};
    a++;
   }
   $(obj).remove();
  }
 });
 
 for(data in objText){
  addField(data, objText[data].text);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add_field_area">
  <div id="add1" class="add">
    <label> Поле №1</label>
    <textarea name="val[]"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>


<input type="button" value="Добавить поле" onClick="addField();">
```

Comment: Может вы знаете, почему если использовать `$('textarea').autoResize(); `, то при удалении блока в центре, очищается все содержимое центральных блоков, текст остается только в 1 и последнем блоке.

Comment: @Erm Приведите код с autoResize, гляну, у меня просто с jquery не очень и с этим плагином не работал

Comment: Возник небольшой вопрос, уже пару дней не получается его исправить. Я добавил вложенных блоков и теперь при удалении очищается все содержимое, может надо поправить что-то в путях? Я пытался, но у меня не вышло. Код добавил

Comment: @Erm скинь полный код, где нибудь на codepen

Comment: https://codepen.io/erm/pen/KQawMz

Comment: @Erm вечером дома буду, гляну